# How to make S3 object downloadable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Some files are served on the browser while others are force downloaded. How to make a file as downloadable on AWS S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of all the storage options provided by AWS, the fastest way your file reaches your user is through AWS S3. It has the option to serve flat files like videos, images and executable files.

To make an S3 object downloadable; change the meta-data to Content-Disposition.

1. Navigate to your S3 bucket
2. Select the S3 object which you want your user to download
3. Click More (dropdown)
4. Select Change Metadata
5. Add `Content-Disposition` as Key and `attachment; file=”yourfilename.extension"` as value.